# Divide and Conquer - Minimum Change - Return Coins as Array

Tags: python, algorithm, divide-and-conquer

Below is a brute-force solution to the minimum coin change problem. It takes an int A, which is the change that needs made, and an array of coin denominations. It returns an object, results, which has the minimum coins that can be returned based on array of coin denominations as well as the array of coins.

For example, if asked to give change for `10` cents with the values `[1, 2, 5]`, it should return `2` coins min and an array `[0, 0, 2]` for two dimes.

It returns the correct min value but not the correct coins array.

```
# values the algorithms should return, the min num of coins, the actual    
# coins in an array, and the original 

# array of coin denominations
class Results:

    a = 0
    change = []
    coinsDenom = []

# A is an array of coin denominations
# C is the change to be made
# returns results object
def changeslow(A, C):
    res = Results()
    res.coinsDenom = C
    res.change = []
    # initialize your change array to be the length of the coindenom array
    for i in range(0, len(res.coinsDenom)):
        res.change.append(0)

    minCoins = A

    for i in [j for j in C if j <= A]:
        if j == A:
            res.a = 1
            res.change[i] = res.change[i] + 1
            return res

        nextcall = changeslow(A-i, C)
        numCoins = 1 + nextcall.a

        if numCoins < minCoins:
            minCoins = numCoins
            res.change = nextcall.change
            res.change[0] = res.change[0] + 1



    res.a = minCoins

    return res
```

Comment: Don't use `i`/`j`/`A`/`C`  for variables that represent things... it makes it *much* more difficult for someone else to maintain/troubleshoot your code.

Comment: What is your question? Do you need help debugging this? [mcve]

Comment: It returns the correct min value but not the correct coins array.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is best solved by using `dynamic programming`. For example, refer to this http://www.columbia.edu/~cs2035/courses/csor4231.F07/dynamic.pdf for the following intuitive dynamic programming formulation:

[image]

```
# DP-CHANGE
# find number of coins needed to represent a value and memoize the last coin
def DP_CHANGE(denoms, value):
    num_coins = [0]*(value+1) # store number of coins needed to represent coin values from [0..value]
    last_coin = [float('Inf')]*(value+1) # memoize last coin used to represent coin values from [0..value]
    for d in denoms:
        num_coins[d] = 1
    for i in range(1, value + 1):
        num_denom = min([(num_coins[i-d] + 1, d) for d in denoms if i - d >= 0])
        num_coins[i], last_coin[i] = num_denom[0], num_denom[1]
    return num_coins, last_coin

# TRACE-CHANGE
# back-trace the denominations used
def TRACE_CHANGE(value, last_coin):
    denoms_used = []
    while value > 0:
        denoms_used.append(last_coin[value]);
        value-=last_coin[value]
    return denoms_used

def FIND_CHANGE(value, denoms):
    num_coins, last_coin = DP_CHANGE(denoms, value)
    print 'number of coins needed to represent values ' + str(range(value+1)) + ': ' + str(num_coins)
    print 'minimum number of coins need to represent the value ' + str(value) + ': ' + str(num_coins[value])
    print 'coins of denominations needed:' + str(TRACE_CHANGE(value, last_coin))

FIND_CHANGE(10, [1,2,5])
# number of coins needed to represent values [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]:
#                                            [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2]
# minimum number of coins need to represent the value 10: 2
# coins of denominations needed:[5, 5]
```